# Custom Login Page and URL - what was delivered?

Tags: apex, visualforce, authentication

This idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqQmAAK requesting the ability to be able to define a custom login page (e.g. with you own branding) is marked as "delivered" but with no link to what was actually delivered.

But there is still activity on this thread http://brianpeddle.com/2011/06/06/building-a-custom-salesforce-login/ that dates from 2011.

What is the best way to create a custom login page (for a standard "salesforce" or "salesforce platform" licensed user that logs in to the normal salesforce pages i.e. not sites) today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement [My Domain](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/domain_name_overview.htm) and enable [SSO](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/How_to_Implement_Single_Sign-On_with_Force.com), what this then does is give you a custom URL for your org.

Eg acme.my.salesforce.com

When you navigate to this URL, rather than presenting the login.salesforce.com screen, it sends browser redirect with a SAML Request to your configured IdP, which can then present a branded login screen.

Comment: The "My Domain" feature is cool, but appears to be just a way to change the initial and subsequent URLs to include your brand name. I'm looking to use the normal built in IdP (salesforce username/password) but just with different content in the login page: are you saying that this is possible via the SSO mechanism? Can you point me to more detail on how?

Comment: There may be an option to do this without My DOmain and SSO (the newly announced Communities or existing Portals), but i can certainly vouch for the My Domain /SSO approach, as in this way you are delegating the Identity Management to a 3rd party, eg ADFS or Ping, where you can set up your own custom Login Page, which is presented by the IdP when someone tries to login.