# Create login to custom community on public site (Site Class Constructor)

Tags: apex, community, force.com-sites, site.com

I have a custom public site that leads customers to join a customer community.  I want to embed the login page in my public site via iframe.  However, the issue is that the iframe X-ORIGIN will not allow a different domain.

I've embedded visualforce page for login that uses a custom controller (below).

What I'm finding is that the custom login controller relies on a parent URL or Site Class to login the community.  I'm thinking if I can set the site to one of my communities manually then I can authenticate and open up a new browser window into the community.

```
 global PageReference login() {
        Site s = new Site();
        //not sure what goes here to make this happen
        return s.login(username, password, '/vfAMCC_Redirect');        
    }
```

Comment: Instead of creating a new site instance, you need to use `return site.login(username,password, yourPageLink)` Also refer to this for more info. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49861/is-there-a-way-to-customize-partner-portal-login-url

Comment: That is how it's done when the login site is a part of the community page (same URL).   If my community site is comun.force.com/communityName and then I have a page /login that return site will work.  If I host the same visualforce page elsewhere it won't login to the community because the parent site is not comun.force.com/community.

Comment: You'd be violating security by attempting to log-in from anyplace that's not on a Salesforce domain unless you configure SSO. What you're attempting to do isn't going to pass muster and isn't supported by the platform.

Comment: I figured because it was on a Salesforce Site (in my org) that it would be okay to do

Comment: @crmprogdev if it's a site off my Org is that possible?

Comment: Only if the two are in the same the subdomain would it potentially be possible. Even then, using an i-frame is not a good idea because of the CRSF potential. Having it open in a new window would be an entirely different matter.